# Conditionally add class to a parent class

Tags: jquery

I have same many `h2` in the page, but want to add class to a specific parent `h2` by jquery conditional statement, example given below:

```
<h2> Top Test Text </h2>
<h2> Test Text <i class="child"></i> </h2>
```

add class to only parent `h2` of `class="child"` not to top h2,
I mean add class to parent `h2`, if `class="child"` is present in the page.

How to do this by jquery?

I have tried this:
See here not working: http://jsfiddle.net/s5dkbuwe/

Thanks.

Comment: probably because you didn't even try code out any jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has()`:

```
$('h2').has('i.child').addClass('foo');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69x9gt9v/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery first. For including jquery, you have two way: 1. you can include from the web. 2. You can download it and use local version. For including it, add this line inside of page's `<head>` section.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then Try this:

```
$("i.child").parent("h2").addClass("your desired class");
```

Comment: i'm learning jquery, so please explain, what you mean "include jquery" ?

Comment: Thanks Hamed for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than connecting to the child element and working backwards, try connecting to all H2's containing a child with the desired class!

```
$("H2:has(>.child)").addClass('yourcustomclass');
```

Note: Using '>' ensures that you select only H2s with a direct child matching the second selector (as opposed to simply having a matching element nested anywhere within the H2 element and its own children).

Answer (score -1):

```
$("h2 i.Child").parent().addClass("theclass")
```

Sample code:

```
        <h2>here</h2>
    <h2>fff <i class="child">sss</i></h2>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("h2 i.child").parent().addClass("blue");
    </script>
```

Comment: @floor, I just tested following code, it worked:
        <h2>here</h2>
        <h2>fff <i class="child">sss</i></h2>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("h2 i.child").parent().addClass("blue");
        </script>